# MAX and SUM function with JOINING tables

Tags: sql, database, join

I have two tables which is `CustomerOrder` and `Customers`

```
CustomerOrder
CusOrderID      CusID     OrderTotalPrice
S01             C01       180
S02             C04       50
S03             C05       70
S04             C07       46
S05             C09       78
S05             C09       164

Customers
CusID    CusName  
C01      James
C02      Jabrial
C03      Maxi
C04      Lim
C05      Tan
C06      Rem
C07      Subaru
C08      Jay
C09      Felix
```

I would need an output which is the customer who spent most on buying books where the display would look like this

```
CusID    Name     OrderTotalPrice
C09      Felix    242
```

I need to use max and sum function and join those two table together and display only one Customer which spend the most. How can I write the query ?
this below is my sample query which doesn't really work
it's Microsoft SQL and TOP function is also not encouraged.

```
SELECT MAX(s.Sum_OrdTotalPrice) AS max
From  (SELECT CO.CusID,C.CusName,SUM(CO.OrderTotalPrice) AS Sum_OrdTotalPrice 
        FROM CustomerOrder CO
            INNER JOIN Customers C On CO.CusID = C.CusID
            Group by CO.CusID,C.CusName
    )s
```

Comment: MySQL 5.x or MySQL 8?  *(And if you just want one row, why not use `ORDER BY Sum_OrdTotalPrice DESC LIMIT 1`?)*

Comment: Your edit says `it's SQL`, but MySQL is SQL, do you mean `Microsoft SQL Server`?  In which case, you need `SELECT TOP (1) ...`  It ***matters*** as to exactly which database product you are using.

Comment: Yes it's microsoft SQL server and we are also not encouraged to use top 1 as top 1 only displays the 1st row where if there's a repeated maximum value it only displays one row of it

Comment: ***Then include that requirement in your question.***

Comment: Avoiding `TOP (1) WITH TIES` for the reason of 'just because' is fundamentally self defeating.

Answer (score 1):

Order the results and take just the first row?

```
    SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES
           CO.CusID,C.CusName,SUM(CO.OrderTotalPrice) AS Sum_OrdTotalPrice 
      FROM CustomerOrder CO
INNER JOIN Customers C On CO.CusID = C.CusID
  GROUP BY CO.CusID,C.CusName
  ORDER BY SUM(CO.OrderTotalPrice) DESC
```

***EDIT 1:*** Changed to SQL Server Syntax, following edit to question

***EDIT 2:*** Added `WITH TIES` so that multiple rows are returned if multiple customers are tied for highest spend

Comment: Sorry MatBailie it's not Mysql it's sql server so limit couldn't be utilized

Answer (score 0):

Should pretty much yield the same results a MatBailie, including ties, but avoids using TOP if that is an absolute necessity

```
SELECT 
Results.CusID, Results.Name, Results.OrderTotalPrice 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        CustomerOrder.CusID, Customers.CusName as Name
        , SUM(CustomerOrder.OrderTotalPrice) as OrderTotalPrice
        , RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(CustomerOrder.OrderTotalPrice) DESC) as SalesRank
    FROM CustomerOrder
    JOIN Customers ON Customers.CusID = CustomerOrder.CusID
    GROUP BY CustomerOrder.CusID, CusName
) Results
WHERE Results.SalesRank = 1
```